# Response parser error

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

This is a cross-domain AJAX request to my web service.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                  url: 'http://storage.loc/api/getowners/?host=http://www.mail.ru/&callback=parseJSON',
                  dataType: 'jsonp',
                  crossDomain: true,
                  type: 'GET',
                  jsonp: false,
                  jsonCallback: 'parseJSON',
                  error: function(){
                      alert('Error');
                  },
                  complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                      alert(textStatus);
                  }
                  });
                });

        function parseJSON(data)
        {
            var links = [];
            $.each(data.users, function(key,value) {
                links.push = '<a href="#" id="'+value+'"onClick="getData(this)">'+value+'</a><br />';   
            });
        }
```

The response is:

```
parseJSON({"users":{"user0":"rulezz87","user1":"karazyab"}})
```

The response seems to be correct, but textStatus is "parsererror" and array in parseJSON() is empty. I`m not a pro in jQuery, so can you tell me, what i did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is incorrect sinde the list of users is not an array. It should be like:

```
{ "users" : [ {"user0" : "rulezz87"}, {"user1" : "karazyab"} ] }
```

So, the error message is correct and the fact that it cannot parse from JSON also.

Comment: I rewrote my code, and know the response is: parseJSON({ "users" : [ {"user0" : "rulezz87"}, {"user1" : "karazyab"} ] }), but it still doesn`t parse it :(